# Kunena forum permissions problem

Tags: forum

I am using a [Kunena forum](http://www.kunena.org/), and I have made some pages accessible only for a new group made by me named "Member".

The problem is that when I make someone "Member", some of them can see the pages and some cannot. I have no idea what's the problem because I use the same mode to make all of them "Member".

Comment: Is the group name case-sensitive? `(Member and member)`

Comment: I don't write the name, I just choose it from a menu. I have a menu with several options: Registred ( all members after they create the accout), Public (all members without accounts), Super Users ( admins) and Member ( the group made by ). On the forum I have some pages for Public users, some for Registred and some for Member.

Answer (score 1):

Check user permissions as well as group permissions.

If it is a 'only some have this issue and some do not' then it is probably due to an issue like user permissions (the only 1 I can think of right now).

Also, try doing a backend movement of some users to 'member' and then see if it works, if it does, it could be a frontend issue with having them move from registered to member.

You should also consult the kunena forum as somebody else may already have had this issue and it has already been answered.